# How to get the MAC Address of CLIENTS/USERS in different LANS?

Tags: linux, perl, bash, unix, redhat

**Scenario: Main Linux Server is Connected to Local Switch Gateway. From Gateway to the network.**

Now i can able to get the IP of the Remote Clients/Users who logged into the Server.
**Linux Command : **"who -u" (gives me the IP Address of the users IP Address).****

For getting the MAC Address of the same user. I tried the arp -a command, It gave the switch MAC-Address only. I cant able to get the Remote Clients/User MAC Address.
**Linux Command : "arp -a" (gives me the MAC Address of the Switch).**

> ***How to the MAC Address of the Remote Clients Machines ?***

**Note :** My Client Machines can run on any OS (Windows/Linux/Solaris).

Comment: try at http://superuser.com/ or http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MAC addresses doesn't get routed, so the IP address would have to be of a host on your network. You will have to ping the IP address first and then use `arp -a`; like

```
ping <Remote_IP_Address>
arp -a <Remote_IP_Address>
```

See this related posts here

[is-there-a-way-to-find-the-mac-address-of-a-remote-machine-i-have-connected-to-w](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41990/is-there-a-way-to-find-the-mac-address-of-a-remote-machine-i-have-connected-to-w)

[how-to-find-the-mac-address-of-a-remote-computer](https://superuser.com/questions/188799/how-to-find-the-mac-address-of-a-remote-computer)

Comment: Yes i tried that also, It was **resulting in same Switch MAC only**. Not the Remote Client MAC Address. 

I tried `nmap <IP Address>` also. It is also not scanning the MAC Address

IP Address -> `who -u` Linux Command.

Comment: Well, check those thread I have mentioned; they have got good info. See if that helps.

Comment: @user3477908, if this answer helped you then try accepting it as answer.